# IIS Rewrite rule %2520 to %20

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, double

```
 <rule name="Rewrite %2520">
 <match url="^sites/SubSite/CCC/SharePoint%2520Portal" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="sites/SubSite/CCC/SharePoint%20Portal" />
```

I'm trying to change %2520 to %20 in a path. The IIS rewrite rule I have is above. It's not redirecting. Any ideas?

The resulting url should be..

URL:
http://vmsp01:888/sites/SubSite/CCC/SharePoint%2520Portal/SalesTableListPageOpen.aspx?&WDPK=initial&WMI=EPCCCSCustTableOpenList&WCMP=YUA

New URL:
http://vmsp01:888/sites/SubSite/CCC/SharePoint%20Portal/SalesTableListPageOpen.aspx?&WDPK=initial&WMI=EPCCCCustTableOpenList&WCMP=YUA

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in regexp instead `%25` you should use `\%`, because    %25 is encoded %. In your case it should be :

```
<match url="^sites/SubSite/CCC/SharePoint\%20Portal" />
```